# Have an item start at half a row and column location

Tags: css, css-grid

Say you have a grid with 5 columns and 4 rows.

So instead of an item being at column 5 and row 1, you would have it column 4.5 and row 1.5.

[image]

Would a transform be the right choice here to move that item?
Or is there a neat built in grid function that allows you to move items to be a certain value between rows and columns?

Comment: Can you share a (relevant) "*[mcve]*" sample of your code, and current attempted approach to solve the problem? It's easier for us to post an answer if we have representative code to work with/from.